# Regexp pattern to stop at &lt;

Tags: java, html, regex

I have some String like this

```
String text = "&gt;www.stackoverflow.com&lt;something else"
```

now I'm looking for a regexp pattern to capture solely www.stackoverflow.com but keep in mind that the URL can contain the ampersand. The pattern needs to match exactly the `&lt;` substring.

I have so far this regexp:

```
(www.)([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\\+,.~#?!&\\/=äöü]+(?![&lt]).)
```

but, of course, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use positive lookahead:

```
(www\\.)([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\\+,.~#?!&\\/=äöü]+)(?=&lt;)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aB5aB7/1)

Comment: thanks, this works great for my exsample but what if there is a space between the URL and `&lt;` ? say: `&gt;www.stackoverflow.com &lt;something else`

Comment: ok then you can use: `(www\\.)([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\\+,.~#?!&\\/=äöü]+)(?=\\s*&lt;)` regex

Comment: sorry to ask again but I can't figure it out actually. What do I have to do if there isn't an `&lt;` at all ?

Comment: Oh but that changes problem totally. I guess then you need to define the rule clearly when to stop matching.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use regexp?

```
text.substring(text.indexOf("www"), text.indexOf("&lt"))
```

gets job done.

Comment: be careful with substring() if your jdk ver < 1.7

Answer (score 0):

```
.*?(www.*?)&lt.*
```

This will work.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oO8zI4/4